# $\left(y+y \sqrt{x^{2} y^{4}-1}\right) d x+2 x \ d y=0$ differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

I am solving the differential equation
$$\left(y+y \sqrt{x^{2} y^{4}-1}\right) d x+2 x \ d y=0$$
and I have to use the substitution $u=xy^{2}$ to find the generic solution:

I have expressed $$y'=dy/dx = -\frac{y(1+ \sqrt{x^2y^4-1})}{2x}$$ I have $u'=y^{2}+2xy y'$, hence $u'=-y^{2}\sqrt{u^2-1}$. (I just substituted $y'$ from initial equation and substituted $u^{2}$ for $x^{2}y^{4}$.)
So $xu'=-u \sqrt{u^2-1}$. Then, $$\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{(u^2-1)}}=\int \frac{-dx}{x} .$$ 
I solved the integral and got that the right-hand side is $-\ln|x|$, for the left side I used the substitution $u = \cosh t , d u = \sinh t\, dt$, which gives $\sqrt{u^2-1}=\sinh t$ and got the answer $\arctan(\sinh t)+c$, which is $\arctan({\sqrt{u^2-1}})+c$; but what do I have to do with it next? 
**Question**: I don't understand the next step after i have $\arctan(\sqrt{u^2-1}) = -\ln|x|+c$ 
upd: Just saw this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2485938/1152290), which is only different because of sign under root, but I don't get how is their left integral $\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{(u^2+1)}}$ is turned into $\ln|u|-\ln|1+\sqrt{u^2+1}|$?

Comment: There might be nothing you can do. You might be able to solve for $u$ and then in term solve for $y$, but you might sacrifice some generality due to noninvertibility of some of the functions (without restricting the domain). Many times you will come across an "implicit solution," one where the function cannot be cleanly solved for, and that's fine sometimes.

Comment: no, i understand how to get this answer.

Comment: i don't understand what is the next step in solving this differential equation. how do turn arctan(sqrt(u^2-1)) to logarithm so that i can equate them with -ln|x| and remove ln

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. $\arctan$ does have a [logarithmic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) but you probably are not supposed to use that. If you happen to have an initial condition in order to determine a particular $C$, then you can go on to solve for $y$, starting by applying $\tan$ to both sides.